# Installing and using jquery plugins

Tags: javascript, jquery, plugins, jquery-plugins

Some newbie questions.  First, I would love to get this plugin:

http://archive.plugins.jquery.com/project/getAttributes

but I can't actually download it (arghh!!), I'm going in circles.  Can you tell me exactly what to click to download it?

Then, how do I install?  This is my first js plugin, and it will really help for what I'm doing. Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is a problem(actually a construction) on jQuery plugins site. They removed all download links.